# Dispatching mousedown event to element won't give it focus

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I tried following code to intercept `mousedown` event and then to re-dispatch it in order to get under control whenever any element gains focus.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    console.log('mousedown', e);
    if (e.target.getAttribute('id') === 'target' && !e.__redispatched) {
        console.log('cancelling');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        setTimeout(function () {
            var re = new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true,
                view: window,
                screenX: e.screenX,
                screenY: e.screenY,
                clientX: e.clientX,
                clientY: e.clientY,
                ctrlKey: e.ctrlKey,
                shiftKey: e.shiftKey,
                altKey: e.altKey,
                button: e.button,
                buttons: e.buttons,
                relatedTarget: e.relatedTarget,
                region: e.region
            }); 
            re.__redispatched = true;
            document.getElementById('target').dispatchEvent(re);
        }, 100);
    }

})
    </script>
    <input id="target" type="text"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Console shows that event is properly re-dispatched, because it's captured by `target` element, but focus is not gained to that element.

When I try that without meddling into events, focus is gained right before `mousedown` event is processed.

Is it possible to handle this behavior just by re-dispatching `mousedown` event or do I have to manually process `focus`?
Or do I do something wrong with the event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `focus` is triggered after receiving the `mousedown` event. However the browser does not run default handlers for [untrusted events](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#trusted-events) such as `MouseEvent` fired using `dispatchEvent`.

You have to `focus` the input manually.

Comment: Thanks, this is an answer I really needed. (I have always thought I had done a bad workaround when I have been unable to get MouseEvents to do what I thought they should do.)